# Show overridden method indicator in Visual Studio Code with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to show an indicator of overridden methods when programming  with Python in Visual Studio Code?

I'm looking for something similar to the icon in the left margin that PyCharm shows when you override a method from a superclass?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment and I'm not sure if the language server protocol supports such a concept. But if it does then you can make a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server.